# Which query is faster for this SQL Zoo question

Tags: sql

I was solving this question on SQL Zoo

> Find the capital and the name where the capital is an extension of
>   name of the country.
>   You should include Mexico City as it is
>   longer than Mexico. You should not include Luxembourg as the capital
>   is the same as the country.

There are two solutions to it

```
SELECT capital,name
FROM world
WHERE capital LIKE concat(name,'_%')
```

```
SELECT name, capital FROM world WHERE capital LIKE concat('%', name, '%') AND capital > name;
```

Can anyone tell me which will be faster and why ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not simply run them and examine their execution plans, and figure that answer out for yourself?

Comment: _where the capital is an extension of name of the country_... does it mean capital needs to _start with_ the country name or can it contain the country name anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

The two queries do not do the same thing -- although they might work for the data set you are using.

In particular, in the second, the `like` pattern starts with a wildcard (`'%'`).  This is going to slow the processing.  More importantly, standard indexes cannot be used when the pattern starts with a wildcard.

Finally, on a dataset with a few hundred rows representing countries, the difference in performance is unlikely to be noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd query's condition:

```
capital LIKE concat('%', name, '%')
```

is not correct because it returns capitals which **contain** the name of the country and not capitals that **start** with the name of the country, regardless the case that there may not exist such capitals (I don't know if they exist).
It should be:

```
capital LIKE concat(name, '%')
```

which combined with the other condition:

```
AND capital > name
```

gives the correct results.
So since both queries use the operator `LIKE` in the `WHERE` clause, I guess the 1st query should be more efficient since it contains only 1 condition.
But you wouldn't even notice the difference in a relatively small table (as is the case of a table that contains as many rows as the countries of the world).

Comment: `like concat(name, '%')` does not check for Luxembourg case.

Comment: This is why you have the 2nd condition capital > name.